# Fedora scientific 26 cannot be downloaded

Tags: fedora, fedora-26

I want to download fedora scientific. I tried, of course [the official website](https://labs.fedoraproject.org/scientific/download/index.html), but it doesn't work. Where can I download it from? I googled this problem but nobody seems to have it. Am I doing sth wrong? 
To be more specific... when I click the download button it redirects me [here](https://labs.fedoraproject.org/scientific/download/scientific-download-splash?file=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/releases/26/Labs/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Scientific_KDE-Live-x86_64-26-1.5.iso)
 and after 2 seconds appears the frustrating 404 Not found.

I went to the fedora forum and found [this archive](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/) with older versions (I guess), but I don't know exactly what to download from there.

If you may, please help me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's not being maintained anymore. There are other ISO files there and the [beta releases for v27 labs](https://labs.fedoraproject.org/prerelease) are there but there's not a *scientific* one.

I would try getting v25 and then updating the packages (suggestion taken from [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/108356/where-is-fedora-26-scientific-labs/)).

The archive you found has Fedora Core releases. Oldies but none seems to be your desired Fedora.